# InvalidSignatureException from POST request

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, axios, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda function that handles reading data from a file(stored inside S3 bucket) as well as inserting data to a Dynamodb table. This Lambda function is exposed as a REST endpoint using API gateway. The function accepts GET request as well as POST request. I'm making GET/POST requests from my REACT project using axios and aws4(for signing) libraries. GET request is to read data from a file stored inside S3 and it works just fine. And POST request is for inserting data into Dynamodb table. However, it doesn't work and AWS returns InvalidSignatureException error as a respond. This is an excerpt of my code :

```
createAWSSignedRequest(postData) {

    let request = {};

    if (postData) {
        request = {
            host: process.env.AWS_HOST,
            method: 'POST',
            url: process.env.AWS_URL,
            path: process.env.AWS_PATH,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(postData)
        }
    } else {
        request = {
            host: process.env.AWS_HOST,
            method: 'GET',
            url: process.env.AWS_URL,
            path: process.env.AWS_PATH
        }

    }


    let signedRequest = aws4.sign(request, {
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY
    });

    return signedRequest;

}
```

This is how GET request is made :

```
let signedRequest = this.createAWSSignedRequest('GET');

axios(signedRequest)
        .then(response => {



        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("error",error);
        });
```

This is how POST request is made :

```
    const data = {
            uuid: "916b7d90-0137-11e8-94e6-116965754e23", //just a mock value
            date : "22/jan/2018",
            user_response: [
                         {
                            question:"this is quesiton1",
                            choice:"user selected A"
                         },
                         {
                            question:"this is quesiton2",
                            choice: "user selected b"
                         },
                         {
                            question:"this is quesiton3",
                            choice: "user selected C"
                         }
                ]
        };



    let signedRequest = this.createAWSSignedRequest(data);



    axios(signedRequest)
        .then(response => {

           ......

        })
        .catch((error) => {

            console.log("error",error);
        });
```

As you can see, the code for both GET and POST requests are exactly the same (except payload and method type). I'm singing with the same secret access key and access key id for both requests. I'm not sure why one request results in "InvalidSignatureException" when the other doesn't. Can anyone shed a light on this issue for me.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with axios, but to me, this doesn't add up: `headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(postData)`  If the body is JSON, how can the content-type be application/x-www-form-urlencoded?  Wouldn't it be `application/json` or something similar?

Comment: You are right. It suppose to be application/json. I just copied it right off Postman that has no issue with POST request. That said, I've tried with application/json but still get the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having discussion with AWS4 lib developer, I figured out what I did wrong. AWS4 uses "body" as a payload attribute to compute signature. However, Axios uses "data" attribute as payload. My mistake was only setting either one of them. So when I set just "data" attribute, the payload was present in the request and content-length is computed correctly. However, the signature was incorrect since the payload was not taken into consideration when computing signature. When I set just "body", payload was not present in the request because Axios does not use "body" attribute for payload. The solution is to set both attributes with payload. I hope this helps to anyone who are having the same issue I have.

Comment: Thank KMC your post helped me to do POST call.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the AWS Amplify library it has a module called `API` which should fit your use cases, and it will perform Sigv4 signing for you either with authenticated or unauthenticated roles. The `Auth` category uses Cognito as the default implementation. For instance:

`npm install aws-amplify --save`

Then import and configure the lib:

```
import Amplify, { API } from 'aws-amplify';
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab', 
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X'
    },
    API: {
        endpoints: [
            {
                name: "APIName",
                endpoint: "https://invokeURI.amazonaws.com"
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Then for your API Gateway endpoint calling a Lambda:

```
let apiName = 'MyApiName';
let path = '/path'; 
let options = {
    headers: {...} // OPTIONAL
}
API.get(apiName, path, options).then(response => {
    // Add your code here
});
```

More info here: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that.